# Math with Struct and strlen in C program

Tags: c, struct, strlen

Can anyone explain the following code snippet:  `strlen(S -> S + 5)`

The full code is below, but if I replace `+5` with other numbers `(-1,0,1,2,3...)` the output has a pattern I cannot discern and therefore I am asking how the value is determined.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct S {
        char *S;// = 1 BYTE EACH
    };

    int main(void) {
        struct S *S = (struct S *) malloc(sizeof(struct S));//pointer created to Structure S with memory allocated of associated size.
        S -> S = "123\0""45678";// Pointer S now pointing to the value S which is holding "123\0""45678" Which has a stop character \0
        printf("%s\n", S->S);// The pointer S points to the string S
        printf("%c\n\n", S -> S[6]);// gives the value, the character, in the   string at [] position
        printf("Length %d\n", strlen(S -> S)); // = 3 because the "\0 stop character stops the count (0,1,2,3)
        printf("Length + 5 = %d\n", strlen(S -> S+ 5)); // = total of 5


        printf("%d", strlen(S -> S + 5) + S -> S[3]);
        free(S);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Note that `strlen(str+5)` is not the same as `strlen(str)+5`. In fact, as long as the string is more than 5 characters, `strlen(str+5)` is the same as `strlen(str) - 5`.

Comment: This question appears to reduce down to "what does `strlen` do, and how does it work?"

Comment: strlen() takes a pointer to char, and counts chars until it hits a \0. So strlen(s + 5) will generally be equal to strlen(s) - 5, unless the string is shorter than 5 characters, in which case it could be anything. Your string is only 3 characters long because you put a \0 in the middle of it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Your blog domain is for sale.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!!  
    S->S + X moves the START of the pointer to X places from the initial 0 position.  
    The NUMBER OF BYTES are then counted from that point to the right until getting to the \0 stop Char.  
    Therefore S->S +2 for the above 1-Byte each character array  is counting from the 2nd position to the  \0 end char ("3" = just 1 byte).
      BUT + 4 starts at "4" (PASt THE \0) and continues to the end ("45678") adding 5 more bytes.
    However, + 6 starts at "6" leaving only 3 char ("678" making only 3 bytes to add for a total of 3 bytes added a LOWER number.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker strlen(S->S+4) is perfectly valid here and will return 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is

```
S->S = "123\0""45678";
```

First of all, `->` is the member access operator for pointers. The trick here is
this:

```
"123\0""45678"
```

In C, when you write two string literals together, they are concatenated into one.
For example

```
const char *txt = "Hello " "world";
puts(txt);
```

would print `Hello world`. And that would be the same as doing

```
const char *txt = "Hello world";
puts(txt);
```

Now `"123\0""45678"` is using the string literal concatenation and it is also using a trick to store
two separate strings at once. Strings are `'\0'`-terminated, usually you don't
need to explicitly use the `'\0'`-terminating byte when you are using string
literals, the compiler does that for you, but you can use it to store multiple
strings at once. The memory of `S->S` looks like this

```
index 0      1     2     3      4     5     6     7     8     9
      +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
      | '1' | '2' | '3' | '\0' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '\0' |
      +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

The second important thing to understand is this:

```
S -> S + 5
```

This is equivalent to

```
&(S->S[5])
```

`S->S + 5` is pointer arithmetic, it's like regular arithmetic with the
difference that the compiler takes care of the size of the object. If you had:

```
int arr[] = { 99, 11, 33, 55 };
```

and you want to get the address of the second element<sup>1</sup> of the array, you can do:
`&(arr[1])`. But you also can use pointer arithmetic and the equivalent
statement would be `arr+1`. The compiler takes care of the size of the `int`
when it's adding the offset (which is `1*sizeof(int)`).

The code above is using both things, the trick with `'\0'`-terminating byte and
pointer arithmetic. That's why when you do

```
printf("%s\n", S->S);
```

`printf` will start printing character by character until it finds the
`'\0'`-terminating byte. `123` is printed on screen. But as you can see, there
are more bytes after the `'\0'`-terminating byte. So if you do

```
printf("%s\n", S->S + 4);
```

it will print `45678`.

---

**fotenote**

<sup>1</sup>In C, you start counting at 0, so the first element is on `arr[0]`,
the second on `arr[1]`, etc.

Comment: @Michi I started counting (in my head) from 0, I should say that in the answer, I'll fix it

Comment: “and you want to get the address of the second element1 of the array, you can do: &(arr[3]).” — Are you sure is not &( arr[1] ) ?

Comment: @Michi ah, yes of course, brain fart, thanks for the feedback, I'll fix the answer

Comment: THANK YOU PABLO. Excellent explanation

Answer (score 0):

`S -> S + 5` is an offset of the string pointer inside the struct (it's 5 characters from the start position), so the length of that substring will vary.
If you use S -> S - 1 then you've gone beyond the start of the string and anything could happen.

If you actually wanted Length + 5 (as your print statement suggests), then you need to move the +5 out of the brackets :)

```
printf("Length + 5 = %d\n", strlen(S -> S) + 5); // = total of 5
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I replace +5 with other numbers (-1,0,1,2,3...) the output has a
>   pattern I cannot discern and therefore I am asking how the value is
>   determined.

For the pointer pointing to:

```
 S -> S = "123\0""45678"
```

These are results of the `strlen`:

```
    // reaching outside the string boundary, Undefined Behaviour
    strlen(S -> S-1)                    // UB: crash, 0 or 4

                                        // Equivalent to: 
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S));     // 3 = strlen("123");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S+1));   // 2 = strlen("23");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S+2));   // 1 = strlen("3");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S+3));   // 0 = strlen("");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S+4));   // 5 = strlen("45678");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(S -> S+5));   // 4 = strlen("5678");
```

Note:

```
size_t strlen ( const char * str );
```

Returns the length of the `C` string `str`.

The length of a `C` string is determined by the terminating null-character.
A `C` string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the `terminating null character` (without including the terminating null character itself). The `terminating null character` is `'\0'`.